# I can't install node.js on Windows 7

Tags: node.js, windows-7, windows-7-x64

I got a new machine with Windows 7 built-in and it is also activated. But when I tried to install node.js it gave me this prompt. It is 64-bit operating system

[image: I have Windows 7 and it gives me this prompt]

Is there a way I can install it or I should install Windows 10 then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently some newer versions don't support win 7, what you can do is try to download an older one like 10.14.2 LTS

Comment: but using an outdated version isn't also good. I might get some more problems then maybe

Comment: Of course using an outdated version is not favorable - however you can ask the same question about still using Windows 7 :)

Comment: Thanks for the help btw. I installed Windows 10 on this machine.

Answer (score 1):

Here i do this

Go to System-Properties (run: systempropertiesadvanced.exe),
in Advanced tab, click Environment Variables.

Still on the System variables,
click 'New', add name: NODE_PATH with value: C:\nodejs64\node_modules, and click OK.
click 'New' again, add name: NODE_SKIP_PLATFORM_CHECK with value: 1, and click OK.

Click OK of all dialogs close.

Restart your machine, so explore and cmd will get the fresh set of variables.

Answer (score 1):

**How to Install node.js in windows 7 Lastest Version?**
Ans :

1. Download Node.js.msi ver. 13.14.0
2. Download Lastest version of nodejs zip form
3. install node.js 13.14.0 version
4. Go C:/nodejs   delete all files from this folder
5. Extract Lastest node.js zip format
6. Restart Your Terminals or VsCode.

[See Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3vVC.png)

Note:

1. Download Node.js LTS Version in Windows
   (Windows Binary (.zip))
2. Before you Extract Delete All files in C:/nodejs folder
3. You Not needs to Set Variables or other processes of installation.

Thanks You.

Comment: I just installed node 18.12.1 with your method (but also I had both NODE_PATH and NODE_SKIP_PLATFORM_CHECK environment variables set.. I don't know if they had anything to do)

Comment: This method not need to set any environment variables. this automatically set when you install node.js version 13.14.0 [My Github](https://github.com/MeetBhingradiya)

Comment: if you need to use React.js this is easy Method to install node.js.